# How to join the following 3 tables with exactly one ABAP SQL statement

Tags: abap, opensql

I have the following 3 tables with data:

`ZMYTABLE` with columns: `ZUSER` & `ZTCODE` and 2 records

```
elias  VA01  
elias  VF01
```

`AGR_1251` with the records

```
SD_role  VA01  
SD2_role VA01  
SD3_role VA01  
SD_role  VA02  
FI_role  VF01  
FI_role  VF02
```

`AGR_USERS` with records

```
elias  SD_role  
elias  SD2_role   
maria  SD_role  
maria  FI_role
```

I want to display the fields `ZUSER`, `ZTCODE` and `AGR_NAME`.
I want all records from `ZMYTABLE` with the role in which exists each tcode for the specific user, namely:

```
ZUSER---ZTCODE---AGRNAME  
elias---VA01-----SD_role  
elias---VA01-----SD2_role  
elias---VF01-----
```

Can someone tell me how to do this by joining the 3 tables with exactly one ABAP SQL statement, in ABAP V7.01 sp07?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I cannot receive the result I want. It is returning only the common ones (1st 2 records).

Comment: ​Question also asked on SCN : https://answers.sap.com/questions/750443/how-to-join-the-following-3-tables.html

Comment: Sandra, is there any problem to put a question in 2 forums? Thanks

Comment: @ekekakos Not a problem at all. But people might find useful related answers, it avoids answering if solved in the other forum, some additional information may be given, etc. It's something I would personally do if I ask two questions occurring in the same context.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it easier to use `UNION`, the first SELECT will return the lines which correspond to the transactions which match one of the user roles (elias, VA01, SD_role and SD2_role), and the second one will return the lines which correspond to the transactions which don't match any of the user roles (elias, VF01).

I tested it by replacing ZMYTABLE with USR07.

```
    SELECT usr07~bname, usr07~tcode, agr_1251~agr_name
      FROM agr_users
      INNER JOIN usr07
        ON usr07~bname EQ agr_users~uname
      INNER JOIN agr_1251
        ON agr_1251~agr_name EQ agr_users~agr_name
           AND agr_1251~low  EQ usr07~tcode
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT usr07~bname, usr07~tcode, ' ' AS agr_name
      FROM usr07
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM agr_users
          INNER JOIN agr_1251
            ON agr_1251~agr_name EQ agr_users~agr_name
          WHERE usr07~bname  EQ agr_users~uname
            AND agr_1251~low EQ usr07~tcode )
    INTO TABLE @DATA(result).
```

It gives these results (formatted for ABAP Unit) :

```
    SORT result BY bname tcode agr_name.
    TYPES ty_result LIKE result.
    assert_equals( act = result exp = VALUE ty_result(
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' agr_name = 'SD2_role' )
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' agr_name = 'SD_role'  )
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VF01' agr_name = ''         ) ) ).
```

Below is the ABAP Unit test code to demonstrate that it works, and you may play with it if needed. You need ABAP 7.52 (Open SQL Test Double Framework).

```
CLASS ltc_main DEFINITION FOR TESTING DURATION SHORT RISK LEVEL HARMLESS
      INHERITING FROM cl_aunit_assert.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    METHODS test FOR TESTING.
    CLASS-METHODS: class_setup, class_teardown.
    CLASS-DATA environment TYPE REF TO if_osql_test_environment.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS ltc_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD class_setup.
    environment = cl_osql_test_environment=>create( i_dependency_list = VALUE #( 
          ( 'USR07' ) ( 'AGR_1251' ) ( 'AGR_USERS' ) ) ).
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD test.
    TYPES ty_usr07 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF usr07 WITH EMPTY KEY.
    TYPES ty_agr_1251 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF agr_1251 WITH EMPTY KEY.
    TYPES ty_agr_users TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF agr_users WITH EMPTY KEY.

    environment->insert_test_data( EXPORTING i_data = VALUE ty_usr07(
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' timestamp = 1 )
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VF01' timestamp = 2 ) ) ).
    environment->insert_test_data( EXPORTING i_data = VALUE ty_agr_1251(
      ( agr_name = 'SD_role'  low = 'VA01' counter = 1 )
      ( agr_name = 'SD2_role' low = 'VA01' counter = 1 )
      ( agr_name = 'SD3_role' low = 'VA01' counter = 1 )
      ( agr_name = 'SD_role ' low = 'VA02' counter = 2 )
      ( agr_name = 'FI_role ' low = 'VF01' counter = 1 )
      ( agr_name = 'FI_role ' low = 'VF02' counter = 2 ) ) ).
    environment->insert_test_data( EXPORTING i_data = VALUE ty_agr_users(
      ( uname = 'elias' agr_name = 'SD_role ' )
      ( uname = 'elias' agr_name = 'SD2_role' )
      ( uname = 'maria' agr_name = 'SD_role ' )
      ( uname = 'maria' agr_name = 'FI_role ' ) ) ).

    "<==== here insert the ABAP SQL provided above & expectations to verify

    ROLLBACK WORK.

  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD class_teardown.
    environment->destroy( ).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

If you have an ABAP release < 7.50, `UNION` is impossible, instead define 2 separate `SELECT`, the first one with `INTO TABLE @DATA(result)` and the second one with `APPENDING TABLE result`.

---

PS: I also did the following tests, inspired from the other answers, they don't work (most of them return the role "FI_role" for "VF01", instead of an empty role).

Failed attempt 1-A:

```
     SELECT usr07~bname, usr07~tcode, agr_1251~agr_name
       FROM agr_users
       INNER JOIN usr07
         ON usr07~bname EQ agr_users~uname
       INNER JOIN agr_1251
         ON agr_1251~agr_name EQ agr_users~agr_name AND
            agr_1251~low      EQ usr07~tcode
       INTO TABLE @DATA(result).
    SORT result BY bname tcode agr_name.
    TYPES ty_result LIKE result.
    assert_equals( act = result exp = VALUE ty_result(
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' agr_name = 'SD2_role' )
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' agr_name = 'SD_role' ) ) ).
```

Failed attempt 1-B:

```
     SELECT DISTINCT usr07~bname,
                 usr07~tcode,
                 agr_1251~agr_name
           FROM usr07
           INNER JOIN agr_1251
             ON agr_1251~low EQ usr07~tcode
           INNER JOIN agr_users
             ON agr_users~uname EQ usr07~bname
           WHERE
              agr_users~agr_name EQ agr_1251~agr_name OR EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM agr_users AS inner_agr_users
              INNER JOIN agr_1251 AS inner_agr_1251
                ON inner_agr_1251~agr_name EQ inner_agr_users~agr_name
              WHERE
                inner_agr_users~agr_name EQ agr_1251~agr_name
           )
           INTO TABLE @DATA(result).
    SORT result BY bname tcode agr_name.
    TYPES ty_result LIKE result.
    assert_equals( act = result exp = VALUE ty_result(
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' agr_name = 'SD2_role' )
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' agr_name = 'SD_role' )
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VF01' agr_name = 'FI_role' ) ) ).
```

Failed attempt 2:

```
     SELECT b~bname, b~tcode, a~agr_name
       FROM agr_1251 as a
       INNER JOIN usr07 as b
         ON a~low EQ b~tcode
       INNER JOIN agr_users as c
         ON a~agr_name EQ c~agr_name
       INTO TABLE @DATA(result).
    SORT result BY bname tcode agr_name.
    TYPES ty_result LIKE result.
    assert_equals( act = result exp = VALUE ty_result(
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' agr_name = 'SD2_role' )
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' agr_name = 'SD_role' )
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VA01' agr_name = 'SD_role' )
      ( bname = 'elias' tcode = 'VF01' agr_name = 'FI_role' ) ) ).
```

Comment: Sandra, unfortunately, the system is an old one ECC6 V7.01 sp07, so there is no UNION. Anyway thanks.

Comment: For these older systems, use 2 SELECT, the second one with `APPENDING TABLE` instead of `INTO TABLE`.

Comment: I am trying to solve this problem by using 2 tables, 1 with the common records (1st 2  in my example) and another 1 with all correct records in numbers but without being empty the appropriate AGR_NAME field.  So I will loop into the 2nd table and I will read the 1st one with key all 3 fields. If sy-subrc <> 0 then I will empty the AGR_NAME field of the record. This is a BAD solution in my eyes, but there is no other direct solution until now.

Comment: @ekekakos You are asking a question, and I give you an answer that I have tested and it gives the exact result you want (it's demonstrated by using ABAP Unit, 7.52 needed though, so I understand you can't execute it, but just trust me). I also explained how to replace `UNION` in your ABAP version. I don't understand why you say you still don't have a solution.

Comment: Sandra when say I DO NOT HAVE A SOLUTION I mean with a direct call to the DB with joins and not multiple calls in db with your solution or mine. I hope that I make myself clear.

Comment: @ekekakos Now it's clear. Question updated to mention your requirement of only one SQL statement & ABAP 7.01 explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

DB access should look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT zmytable~zuser,
                zmytable~ztcode,
                agr_1251~agr_name
FROM zmytable
INNER JOIN agr_1251
  ON agr_1251.ztcode EQ zmytable.ztcode
INNER JOIN agr_users
  ON agr_users.zuser EQ zmytable.zuser
WHERE
   agr_users.agr_name EQ agr_1251.agr_name OR EXISTS(
   SELECT *
   FROM agr_users AS inner_agr_users
   INNER JOIN agr_1251 AS inner_agr_1251
     ON inner_agr_1251.agr_name EQ inner_agr_users.agr_name
   WHERE
     inner_agr_users.agr_name EQ agr_1251.agr_name
).
```

Add `INTO` clause and deal with the output.

- I am planning to upgrade the answer with explanations when I have time.

Comment: This returns the common records namely the 1st 2 records in my example. Thanks

Comment: @ekekakos fixed

Comment: For information, I have tested the query inside a test program (cf separate answer), it doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: Dorad, unfortunately, it returns the correct number of records but the  field AGR_NAME is not empty for the appropriate records. Thanks Elias

Answer (score 0):

To access all records, you should use DB Access as below.

```
SELECT b~zuser, b~ztcode, a~agr_name
  FROM agr_1251 as a
  INNER JOIN zmytable as b
    ON a~tcode EQ b~tcode
  INNER JOIN agr_user as c
    ON a~agr_name EQ c~agr_name.
```

Rest you can use ABAP to display output.

Comment: For information, I have tested the query inside a test program (cf separate answer), it doesn't give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

**Triple Join** works for version > 7.4.

```
SELECT c~zuser, a~zrole, c~ztcode INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @lt_result
     FROM agr_users AS a INNER JOIN agr_1251 AS b 
         ON a~zrole = b~zrole
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN zmytable AS c 
              ON c~ztcode = b~ztcode AND c~zuser = a~zuser.
```

Comment: Haojie, this is working in version > 7.50 not ours 7.01. Thanks.

Comment: OK. the answer is updated. It should also work in 7.01

Comment: `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` only works in ABAP >= 7.40. I have edited the question to mention it's for ABAP 7.01.

Comment: @SandraRossi Thanks! I will check afterwards in 7.01.